# Open Modal Form from other Modal Form JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using a JQuery [Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) for ask some question to the user, I want that when the user click on OK button (Create an account for demo) open other JQuery Modal Form....

How Can I do it?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but you can actually do modal popups using only css3 now. The modal popup will change based on whatever the value of whats between the brackets is in this web address: www.mysite.com/someURI#{myModal}. [Link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

Comment: But I'm using this jquery plugin... http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: What do you have now? Post up your code and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) but you should be able to just `$("#dialog-other").dialog()` like you did with the first one when you click ok and close the original form dialog.

Comment: Check in http://jsfiddle.net/zZ93V/1/ When I click on Create new user show it Modal form and I want that click on OK button can show other Modal form